# How to extract selected value in XML

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I would like to extract only a value from similar content XML file.

Example;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<items>   

<channel>
<title><![CDATA[*** text 1 text ***]]></title>
<playlist_url><![CDATA[http://host.net/aa/15_info/]]></playlist_url>
</channel>

<channel>       
<title><![CDATA[*** text 2 text ***]]></title>
<playlist_url><![CDATA[http://host.net/aa/16_info/]]></playlist_url>
</channel>

<channel>      
<title><![CDATA[*** text 3 text ***]]></title>
<playlist_url><![CDATA[http://host.net/aa/vodpr/]]></playlist_url>  
<protected>True</protected> 
</channel>

<channel>
<title><![CDATA[*** text 4 text ***]]></title>
<playlist_url><![CDATA[http://host.net/aa/vodpr/con_tv_r.php]]></playlist_url>
<protected>True</protected> 
</channel>

</items>
```

I need extract seperatly 'http://host.net/aa/vodpr/' and 'http://host.net/aa/vodpr/con_tv_t.php' variable url values.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to get the value of the `playlist_url` nodes for each `channel` node that has a `protected` node with value `True`:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//channel[protected = "True"]/playlist_url' -nl file.xml
http://host.net/aa/vodpr/
http://host.net/aa/vodpr/con_tv_r.php
```

This uses `xmlstarlet` to apply an XPATH query to the document.  The `-nl` at the end adds a terminating newline to the last piece of data.

---

To select the URL that corresponds to the specific text in the `title` node (for example, "contains `text 3`"), use

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//channel[./title[contains(., "text 3")]]/playlist_url' -nl file.xml
http://host.net/aa/vodpr/
```

Here we detect the `text 3` text in the value of the `title` node and select that particular `channel` node.  We then pick the `playlist_url` from it.

Comment: Yes I using xmlstarlet but don't extract seperatly. So just like http://host.net/aa/vodpr/con_tv_r.php

Comment: @AliHaydarDoğan I don't understand. Do you just need one of the URLs or both (as in the question)?  What criteria do you pick the URL(s) by?

Comment: Criteria can be text3 or text4.

Comment: @AliHaydarDoğan See update.

Comment: I have one more question. Example, without criteria like text3 only with playlist url criteria. Result;

http://host.net/aa/15_info/
http://host.net/aa/15_info/
http://host.net/aa/vodpr/
http://host.net/aa/vodpr/con_tv_r.php

Can I choose what we want from the result? Example 3. line or 1. and 3. lines.

Comment: @AliHaydarDoğan I don't really handle followup questions in comments. If you have further issues, consider asking a new question or modify this one to cover all the necessary cases.